# Performance Azure Blob vs Azure Table

Tags: .net, azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage, azure-blob-storage

I have around 300 million text files, ranging from 50kb to 100kb that I need to read and **serve on a web page**.

Remarks:

On Azure Table, I would need to split some of the text files, to make sure it doesn't exceed the maximum of 64kb per column.

On Azure Blob, I would not have the problem of splitting, but would need to store a reference to them on the Azure SQL/Azure Table.

Okay, intro is done! Now, on my Azure Web App:

1. Would be faster to read the text file from Azure Blob or from Azure Table?
2. Would the Azure Table be able to process more requests?

Comment: I did some testing, and, to my surprise, reading the file from the Blob is faster than from Table.

Also, I agree, for search, I plan on using Azure Search.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I agree with Andrei M. The best solution is blob storage with a table service or even a sql database to store reference.

Just one more thing, if you plan to search for content in those file, neither table service / blob will be good for that. If that's the case, I recommend you setup a VM with elastic search / solr and index those contents.

PS: there's also Azure Search, for that, you can give it a try too.

Comment: It's now possible to search in blob.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-howto-indexing-azure-blob-storage

Indexing Documents in Azure Blob Storage with Azure Search
The blob indexer can extract text from the following document formats:
PDF
Microsoft Office formats: DOCX/DOC, XLSX/XLS, PPTX/PPT, MSG (Outlook emails)
HTML
XML
ZIP
EML
Plain text files
JSON (see Indexing JSON blobs preview feature)
CSV (see Indexing CSV blobs preview feature)

Answer (score 6):

Blob storage is better then Table storage if you want to work with files. I definitely would not want to deal with file chunks in a table. If you need to keep references to your blobs, how about combining two options and use Table storage for references? I think this would be the best in terms of performance :).

Comment: Point queries (with partition key and row key) are very fast with table storage. You'd have to do perf testing yourself, but this fact makes Andrei's answer all the more true.

Comment: Even working with strings, blob is faster. I tested. Retrieve 2kb from a file in a blob or from table storage? Blob wins 9 ou of 10